# UIButton setting frame not working?

Tags: objective-c, uibutton

I have written the following code for my app:

```
self.PlayButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];

//Setup Play Button
[self.PlayButton setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
self.PlayButton.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width * 0.38, self.view.frame.size.height * 0.666, self.view.frame.size.width * 0.48, self.view.frame.size.height * 0.29);
[self.PlayButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"PlayButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.PlayButton.layer setMagnificationFilter:kCAFilterNearest];
[self.PlayButton addTarget:self action:@selector(PlayButtonMethod) forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)UIControlEventTouchUpInside]


[self.view addSubview:self.PlayButton];
```

But when this code it run rather than the image appearing in a rather specific location it simply appears in the top left hand corner of the view. Almost like it had been set

```
self.PlayButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width * 0.48, self.view.frame.size.height * 0.29);
```

It's odd because the width and height is put in correctly but for whatever reason the position of the button set by the CGRectMake is not taken into account. Ive done a bit of research into creating UIButtons in code and fro what I've seen not only has this happened to no-one else the code have written is perfectly liable.

Any help would be appreciated.
    Thanks

Comment: My first guess is that it is an autolayout issue. As to how to fix it I am unsure, but you may want to try doing initWithFrame: and seeing if that makes a difference.

Comment: @SkylerLauren Just gave that a try, didn't make a difference :/ This problem is really bogging me down... its happened on all 3 of my buttons.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like ive found the fix:
Removing this line of code fixed the issue for me.

```
[self.PlayButton setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
```

not 100% sure why this was causing the problem but it fixed it.

Comment: You set this to NO when you use constraints to define the layout. I haven't tried it, but I suspect when you set this to NO, and do not set constraints, you get the behaviour you described.

Answer (score 0):

When creating `UIButton`s using the standard `alloc init` method doesn't actually create a button. The method for creating and initializing a `UIButton` is called `buttonWithType:`. This creates a `UIButton` of the specified type if you use `alloc init` it will not work correctly, see the [Apple Documentation for `UIButton`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIButton/buttonWithType:).

So you need to change line

```
self.PlayButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
```

to

```
self.PlayButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
```

`buttonWithType:` allows you to pass in an enum of `UIButtonType` so it will accept any of the following values :

- `UIButtonTypeCustom`
- `UIButtonTypeSystem`
- `UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure`
- `UIButtonTypeInfoLight`
- `UIButtonTypeInfoDark`
- `UIButtonTypeContactAdd`
- `UIButtonTypeRoundedRect`

If you don't pass it a `UIButtonType` the button will not be initialized as it will not know what type of button you want and it will not assume. Also check out the [Apple Documentation for `UIButtonType`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIButtonType)

**Side Note**

I'm just going to include this as a side note. Also have a read of the [Apple Coding Conventions Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Conventions/Conventions.html) as I have noticed that you are using uppercase to start your variable names (i.e. `PlayButton`). Variable names should start with lowercase (i.e. `playButton`) and Class and Enum names should start with uppercase (i.e. `UIViewController`). It's always good to stick to conventions as it makes you code more readable and maintainable so if another developer comes to modify your code it is easy for them or even yourself to read.